# graphic problem after ubuntu upgrade to 15.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, 15.10

I did an upgrade to my ubuntu from 15.04 to 15.10 but after this upgrade I got a graphic problem, sometimes the characters/folders are not clear when I pass the mouse over it and the images too are not clear

my graphic card is : Intel® G45/G43  and I didn't find the new updates of the driver in the Intel website

I don't know if the problem is clear for you guys or not in the picture below

[image]

help me please! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved in this [Link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300925&p=13382022#post13382022) and it was by disabling the SNA acceleration

Answer (score 0):

Launchpad-bug-report exists:

[Garbled graphics in Wily with Intel GMA4500 chip](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1507255) (#1507255)

You can add yourself here, with the informations in question asked for in an ubuntu-wiki-page [X/Testing/SNA](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Testing/IntelSNA) (~2013)

Looks like your graphics are [fourth generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Fourth_generation) (2008?)